# Finding defective chips between set of chips

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

I am an undergrad student-computer science, and while reading some past papers I came across this question:

I solved the question in O(n^2) like this:

1. Picking randomly any chip (pivot), and connecting it with other chips (O(n))
2. if more than of half chips state that the "pivot" is a normal chip I can simply connect it to the other chips and get the defected ones (O(n))
3. WORST CASE: if my picked pivot is a defected chip, then I can't use it, and I will have to check (2n-1) chips, until all defected are found (O(n^2))

Is there any better algorithm-or can anyone suggest any readings so I can get a hint?

Comment: "the defective chips randomly answer to the testing" - so the best you're ever going to be able to do in a finite number of tests is be *very very sure but not certain* about the nature of each chip - after all, there's nothing stopping a defective chip from randomly giving the right answer on every one of the (finite number of) times you test it. Looks like a poorly-set problem to me.

Comment: I don't think this question has an answer without knowing the type-1 and type-2 error probability of the defect chips and the confidence you want to achieve. As an example assume that the defect chips only produce wrong outputs 0.1% of the time, then you will need more checks then when they produce wrong outputs 99% of the time. In any case you cannot be 100% certain no matter how often you test the chips. You can only increase your confidence.

Comment: I totally agree with both of you, but the thing is i think that we can see the defected ones as if they don't give us any answer at all, so when they are connected with any normal-working chip they don't show us anything ( in other words we can't rely on the output given by any defected chip) and in this case it doesn't matter how many times the defected chip is giving a correct answer, or a wrong answer

Comment: See if you can develop the following idea into a full algorithm: Suppose you compare chip i to chip i+1, i+1 to i+2, ..., j-1 to j, and in each comparison both chips report that the other chip is normal.  There are only 2 possibilities: Either all j-i+1 chips are normal, or they are *all* defective -- since if at least 1 was normal and at least 1 defective, there must be an adjacent (normal, defective) pair, and then the normal one would correctly report the other as defective.

Comment: Can you elaborate what index j refers to?

Comment: i and j are any two numbers in the range 1 to 2n and obeying i < j.

Comment: In fact my observation above doesn't apply just to consecutive ranges of chips -- any sequence of chips will work.  I should have written, "Suppose you have a set of m chips {x1, x2, ..., xm}, and you have compared chip x1 to chip x2, chip x2 to chip x3, ..., chip x[m-1] to chip xm, and in each comparison ...".

Comment: I apologize , but i couldn't understand what do you mean by "all defective" , since there can be no more than (n-1) defected chips, can you give an example, i would really appreciate your help

Comment: *If* you grab a handful of chips, order them however you want, compare each one to the next one in the order, and find that they all report that the other chip is normal, *then* they are either *all* normal or *all* defective.

Comment: The reason is that there are only 3 possibilities: (1) they are all normal; (2) they are all defective (and all lying); (3) at least one is normal and at least one is defective.  But possibility (3) cannot happen, since it would imply that at least one comparison just performed was between a normal chip and a defective one, in which the normal chip is obliged to report that the other one is indeed defective.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - no, the original task says that "the defective chips randomly answer to the testing", which means that defective just sometimes answer "good", sometimes "bad" randomly. Also it states that more than half of them are "good", therefore they cannot be all deffective

Comment: @libik: If you think carefully about the scenario I laid out, you will find that possibility (3) can't occur, meaning that the chips in that handful must all be good, or all defective.  If you still disagree, please describe a small counterexample.  (Note I'm talking only about the chips *in the chosen handful*.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker - chip0 and chip 1 are defective, you check them, chip0 says that chip1 is defective, chip1 says that chip0 is ok. All others are ok, when you check the chip1 and chip2, chip1 says chip2 is ok, chip2 says that chip1 is defective. Result of your solution - you consider chip0 as ok, but it is defective.

Comment: @libik: Some chips in your example report that other chips are defective.  In the scenario I was describing, both chips in every comparison report that the other chip is normal ("If you grab a handful of chips, order them however you want, compare each one to the next one in the order, **and find that they all report that the other chip is normal**, then they are either all normal or all defective.")

Comment: @j_random_hacker - well then it does not help you, we need to identify which are good and which are bad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171784/discussion-between-libik-and-j-random-hacker).

Comment: @libik i agree with you, since if i have 2n chips and testing pairwise (any pairs) wouldn't give me any solution, and the possibilty of having all defective or all normal is impossible (as stated in original problem)

Comment: How many times do I have to write that I am talking about all chips *in the handful*?

Comment: @libik: See my answer for a linear-time algorithm that uses the property you thought does not help as one of its two key ingredients.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Why do you want to delete this question?  The only reason I can think of is to conceal evidence that you got outside help in answering a question when you weren't supposed to, and I'm not inclined to help you do that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "exactly" -- do you mean that, yes, you want to conceal evidence that you got outside help when you shouldn't have?  Sorry, but I'm not going to help you do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's not programming related, but a pure math/statistics problem.

Comment: This question is off-topic not because it is not programming related, but because it is POB and asking for a better solution to an existing working solution. From the Help Center on "What topics can I ask about here?" - [...] but if your question generally covers… [...] **a software algorithm**, [...] … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

### A linear-time algorithm

The following algorithm is based on building up information that is *partial* (instead of immediately learning the state of a particular chip, we gradually narrow down the possibilities for sets of chips), but *definite* (we don't rely in any way on probabilities, and in particular we don't assume that a bad chip ever lies, or ever tells the truth).  The following two observations are key:

**Observation 1:** If you grab a handful of chips, order them however you want, compare each one to the next one in the order, and find that they all report that the other chip is normal, then the chips in this handful are either all normal or all defective.  (To see this, notice that the only other possibility is that there is at least one chip of each kind in the handful -- but if this were the case, then there must be at least one pair of *adjacent* chips of each kind, and in that case when these two chips tested each other, the good chip would have correctly reported that the defective chip is defective.  This contradicts our assumption that every chip in the handful reports "good" for all (one or two) tests it is involved in, so it can't happen.)

**Observation 2:** If you know that there are a majority of good chips, and you remove some number of good chips and at least as many bad chips, then a majority of the remaining chips are good.

The algorithm consists of at most log2(n)+1 "pairing phases", each of which does a linear amount of work on the current problem and results in a new problem of half the size, which becomes the current problem for the next phase.  These phases allow us to determine a good chip.  With this in hand, we can then reliably check every other chip in linear time.

The pairing phase algorithm operates on *bags* of chips, where we assume that every chip in the same bag has the same status (either good or defective).  We start out by putting each of the 2n chips in a separate bag, so this condition clearly holds at the outset.  We also assume that a majority of the chips in the input to each phase are good.  The problem statement guarantees that this is true initially.

### Pairing phase

1. Let B be the input set of chip bags, and let M be the subset of B containing only the maximum-size bags (e.g., if B = {{2, 4}, {3, 5, 10}, {7, 8, 9}, {1}}, then M = {{3, 5, 10}, {7, 8, 9}}).
2. If |M| is odd, move one of its bags into a "leftovers" pile.  Also put any non-maximal-size bags in B (i.e., any bags in B but not in M) into the leftovers pile.
3. Arrange the remaining bags in M into |M|/2 pairs in some arbitrary way (e.g., pair the first bag in M with the second, the third with the fourth, etc.).
4. For each pair:

   - Compare some chip from the first bag in the pair with some chip from the second bag in the pair.
   - If the result of the test is that both chips report the other as "good", then combine the two bags of chips in this pair into a single new bag (containing twice as many chips).  According to Observation 1, either all chips in this new double-size bag are good, or they are all defective.
   - Otherwise (when at least one of the two chips reports the other as "defective"), we know that at least one of the two bags in the pair contains only defective chips.  Since the two bags in this pair have the same size, Observation 2 tells us that if we discard *both* bags, the remaining chips will continue to have a majority of good chips.
5. The output of the phase is the set of at most |M|/2 double-size bags, plus the bags in the "leftovers" pile.  That is, we effectively discard the bag pairs from M for which the result of the test was not "good+good".

If we maintain bags as doubly linked lists of chips, we can combine two bags into a single bag in constant time: For any chip x in the first bag and any chip y in the second bag, set x.next.prev = y.prev, y.prev.next = x.next, x.next = y, and y.prev = x.  Doing this of course "destroys" the original two bags, but this is not important for us as we don't need those original bags for any later step.

Every iteration takes a set of bags as input and produces a set of bags as output.  The number of maximum-size bags in the output is at most half the number of maximum-size bags in the input; the number of non-maximum-size bags produced as output grows by at most 1.  The property that a majority of chips are good is maintained.  Thus after at most log2(n)+1 iterations, there will be a unique maximum-size bag (having size equal to some power of 2), plus at most log2(n)+1 smaller bags of distinct sizes (also all having sizes that are (distinct) powers of 2).  At this point we stop.  In this final set of bags, the unique maximum-size bag contains a majority of the chips, since all smaller bags have distinct sizes that are strictly smaller powers of 2.  (This can be formally shown with induction, but perhaps it's enough to see that, say, the number 16, represented in binary as 10000, is larger than any number you can produce by turning on any combination of the lower 4 bits (equivalent to summing distinct smaller powers of 2).)

Since the unique maximum-size bag has a majority of all the chips present in this final set of bags, and we know that the majority of these chips are good, and that every chip in this bag is of the same kind (good or defective), it must be that every chip in this bag is good (if they were bad, there would not be enough chips among the other bags to form a majority of good chips).  So, choose any chip from this bag, and use it to reliably test every other chip.  This final scan also takes linear time, so the algorithm is linear time overall.

### Examples

The following diagram shows how 8 good chips will be dealt with by the algorithm:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
X X X X X X X X   Phase 1: Input (8 1-chip bags)
X-X X-X X-X X-X   Phase 1: Pair up bags and compare each pair using 1 chip in each bag
X=X X=X X=X X=X   Phase 1 output, phase 2 input
X=X-X=X X=X-X=X   Phase 2: Pair up bags and compare each pair using 1 chip in each bag
X=X=X=X X=X=X=X   Phase 2 output, phase 3 input
X=X=X=X-X=X=X=X   Phase 3: Pair up bags and compare each pair using 1 chip in each bag
X=X=X=X=X=X=X=X   Phase 3: Output has a single max-size bag.
```

In the following example, chips 3, 4 and 6 are defective, and chips 3 and 4 both "lie" when compared to each other (each reports the other as good):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
X X ! ! X ! X X   Phase 1: Input (8 1-chip bags)
X-X !-! X-! X-X   Phase 2: Pair up bags and compare each pair using 1 chip in each bag
X=X !=!     X=X   Phase 2: Output (discard chips 5, 6; keep the all-defective bag {3, 4})
X=X-!=!     X=X   Phase 3: Only 2 bags in M to pair up and compare
            X=X   Phase 3: Output discards 1, 2, 3, 4; a single max-size bag X=X remains.
```

In the following example, chips 3, 4 and 6 are defective as before, and chip 3 continues to incorrectly report chip 4 as good, but chip 4 correctly reports chip 3 as defective.  Note that the diagram would be identical in the remaining two cases, where either chip 3 reports chip 4 is good but chip 4 reports chip 3 as defective, or both chips report the other as defective:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
X X ! ! X ! X X   Phase 1: Input (8 1-chip bags)
X-X !-! X-! X-X   Phase 2: Pair up bags and compare each pair using 1 chip in each bag
X=X         X=X   Phase 2: Output (discard chips 3, 4, 5, 6)
X=X---------X=X   Phase 3: Only 2 bags in M to pair up and compare
X=X=========X=X   Phase 3: Output has a single max-size bag.
```

By the end, we have performed a total of at most 2n-1 comparisons (runs of `-` characters) between chips, each of which resulted in at most one join operation.

Comment: First of all thank you ! Actually I understood you observations an they're well explained, but i Couldn't understand the pairing phase "(e.g., if B = {{2, 4}, {3, 5, 10}, {7, 8, 9}, {1}}, then M = {{3, 5, 10}, {7, 8, 9}})."

can you elaborate a little more? I would really appreciate it . thank you once again

Comment: I don't understand how do you start pairing (let suppose we have 10 Chips {c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10}

Do you start grouping like this ?

first phase 10 bags-> 5 bags {{c1,c2}, { } .....}?

Or am i wrong?

Comment: I mean my biggest concern is , how do  you merge to bags/groups , or how do you throw'em away?by comparing what and what exactly?

Comment: @j_random_hacker - Ok, I think I fully understand that now. It is good, reliable approach, but I think there is one thing that you are wrong - it is `O(n*log n)` as in pairing phase, you basically move up to `N/2` into different bags and you repeat this `log n` times. (I think you have considered the only number of comparisons, which is indeed `O(N)`, but you have not considered the amount of work that you have to do after the comparison)

Comment: Thanks @libik.  I should have been clearer about how to combine the bags efficiently -- if you maintain the bags as doubly linked lists, two of them can be joined together in constant time, and this is OK for our purposes as we don't need either of the original bags thereafter.  I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: @DahabShakil: In that example of B and M, you can think of the numbers (2, 4 etc.) as being chip IDs -- you could alternatively write them as {c2, c4}, etc.  B is a set of bags of these chip IDs; in my example, one bag in B is {2, 4}, another is {7, 8, 9} (there are 2 more).  The largest bag in B has 3 chips, so M consists of all bags with 3 chips -- in this case, {3, 5, 10} and {7, 8, 9}.  In each comparison, all we need is *any* chip from the first bag, and *any* chip from the second bag.  Regarding merging bags, I will update the answer soon to explain how 2 bags can be merged in O(1) time.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - Ah, true, linked list can solve that `log n` multiply. However more I think about it is, what you do if you end up with i.e. 4, 3, 2 size subsets. Then you cannot continue in your original progress and you have to de-couple it somehow

Comment: @libik: You can only produce subsets that are distinct powers of 2, so that can't happen.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - example - you have 3 chips: good, good, bad. You do the first checks, first two ends as "good", so you connect them, then you have {good, good} and {bad}. What now?

Comment: @libik: You have a unique maximum-size bag (the {good, good} one), so you stop, knowing that the chips in that bag must be good.

Comment: can you show me how it works with not powers of 2

suppose 30 chips?

Comment: Your summary sounds right.  "because the normal chips' number is bigger right??" -- you seem to be asking for confirmation, but I already explain this in the last paragraph before the examples.  I suggest trying a 30-chip example yourself -- post it as an answer and I'll comment or edit if I see any problems.

Comment: @DahabShakil: Please note I fixed a small bug in the algorithm with my edit: non-maximum-size bags (i.e., those that are in B but not in M) are included in the output of the phase (alongside any new, double-size bags formed).

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: The j_random_hacker is much better solution. I do not want to delete mine, because I do think there is some interesting reasoning there. Actually for similar task in which you dont know number of good/bad chips, this is (probably) still the best linear solution you can come with.

---

As stated in comments, you cannot be never 100% sure, but maybe it is part of the question, to be able to mention the reliability of your solution.

First you have to find the correct chip. We can do it as this:

```
1) i=0
2) take chip[i] and chip[i+1]
3) get their results 1000x times
4) if one chip tells you 1000x times same result, take it as good one
5) if neither of the chip continues with the same result, i=i+2 and continue until you find it
```

This can lead to 1000*2N=2000N repetitions, which is still `O(N)`

The possibility that you are wrong is `1:2^1000`, which is bigger number than the atoms in a universe. Which mean that if there is one atom in whole universe "special" and you have to choose randomly one atom, the chances that you select exactly "that one" are similar to the chances you have selected wrong chip.

After you find good chip, you just compare it with all others to see if they work, which is also `O(N)`

Overal complexity: `O(N)`

Space requirements: `O(1)`, you need at maximum 2 chips in memory and when checking them 1000x, you only need to know the last value from both to see if it is still same.

---

The actual code that should work

```js
class Chip {
    constructor() {
        this.defective = Math.random() < 0.5;
    }

    isOtherChipDefective(chip) {
        if (this.defective) {
            return Math.random() > 0.5;
        }

        return chip.amIDefective();
    }

    amIDefective() {
        return this.defective;
    }
}

function generateChips(size) {
    const chips = [];
    for (let i=0; i < size; i++) {
        chips.push(new Chip());
    }
    return chips;
}

function findGoodChip(chips) {
    for (let i = 0; i < chips.length - 1; i++) {
        let prevRes = null;
        console.log(`trying chip no. ${i}`)
        for (let j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            res = chips[i].isOtherChipDefective(chips[i + 1]);
            if (prevRes === null) {
                prevRes = res;
            }

            if (prevRes !== res) {
                console.log(`chip no. ${i} is defective, found out on ${j} try`)
                break;
            }

            if (j === 999) {
                console.log(`chip no. ${i} is good, found out on ${j} try`)
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function findSolution(chips) {
    const goodChip = chips[findGoodChip(chips)];
    const goodChips = [];
    const badChips = [];
    chips.forEach(chip => {
        if (goodChip.isOtherChipDefective(chip)) {
            badChips.push(chip);
        } else {
            goodChips.push(chip);
        }
    })

    return {goodChips, badChips};
}
const solution = findSolution(generateChips(10));
solution.goodChips.forEach(goodChip => console.log('should be good chip', !goodChip.amIDefective()));
solution.badChips.forEach(badChip => console.log('should be bad chip', badChip.amIDefective()));
```

It has output as this:

```
trying chip no. 0
chip no. 0 is defective, found out on 1 try
trying chip no. 1
chip no. 1 is defective, found out on 3 try
trying chip no. 2
chip no. 2 is good, found out on 999 try
should be good chip true
should be good chip true
should be good chip true
should be bad chip true
should be bad chip true
should be bad chip true
should be bad chip true
should be bad chip true
should be bad chip true
should be bad chip true
```

PS: This algorithm is also not bound to any input - it finds out if all chips are defective, all good or any combination between these two.